# how to move google maps control INURL

Tags: google-maps, user-controls

i have this link:

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=Zagreb,+Croatia&aq=&sll=45.808351,15.897484&sspn=0.010066,0.016544&vpsrc=0&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Zagreb,+Croatia&t=p&z=14&ll=45.794222,16.048298&output=embed

and wish to have the controls (currently in TOP LEFT position) in the 
LEFT_CENTER position as indicated here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlPositioning

what to add to the URL?
thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: You can't do this.

---

This is one instance where the API has more functionality than Google Maps.

There is a list of Maps parameters in [Mapki](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters) — changing the position of controls isn't mentioned.

If you want to do more, you really need to use the API, which is what is covered by the documentation you referenced: that doesn't apply to Google Maps.

Comment: thnx a lot for the link :) that info is not easy to have all in one place. :) i'll wait a bit though, maybe someone found a way, if not i'll mark the answer as accepted.